# Write csv file using CsvHelper, from excel in a dynamic way c#

Tags: c#, .net, csv, export-to-csv, csvhelper

I'm trying to generate a CSV file from excel files. I have different Excel files and I would like to read them and generate a CSV file. I imagine it must be quite easy, but I'm having some trouble.

This is the library I'm supposed to use

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/.

I would appreciate any tutorial or anything on how I can approach this matter.
The idea is to read the first row of my Excel files like headers and then the other rows as values, so I can write the CSV.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your question is very broad and so it is hard to know which part you are stuck on. Are you stuck opening and reading an Excel file? Are you stuck with using the `CsvHelper` library? Is there some other problem you are running into? I suggest breaking your problem down into smaller pieces. Start with reading in an excel file and then move on to the other parts. If you get stuck somewhere then come back and ask again, being sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: yes @pstrjds I'm stuck with reading the exel file in a generic way because every exel is different. So I want the first row of exel to always be the keys (column names of the csv) and the other rows to be the values. Do you understand?

Comment: I understand, but can you please show us what you have tried. What exactly are you stuck on? Are you unable to open the excel file?  Are you unable to parse the excel file?  Please update your question so that it is clear as to what issue you are having. As it stands now it is too broad (as is evidenced by getting an answer related to writing a CSV file, but you now saying in the comments that the issue is related to reading an excel file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string filePath = "C:\\Users\\{User}\\Desktop\\sample.xlsx";
        System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        List<List<object>> rows = new List<List<object>>();
        List<object> row = new List<object>();
        // Excel Reader
        using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream, new ExcelReaderConfiguration
            {
                FallbackEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252),

            }))
            {
                do
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        row.Clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            var field = reader.GetValue(i);
                            if (field is int valueInt)
                            {
                                row.Add(valueInt);
                            }
                            else if (field is bool valueBool)
                            {
                                row.Add(valueBool);
                            }
                            else if (field is DateTime valueDate)
                            {
                                //row.Add(valueDate); You can write any condition there
                                row.Add(valueDate.Year);
                            }
                            else if (field is TimeSpan valueTime)
                            {
                                row.Add(valueTime);
                            }
                            else if (field is string valueString)
                            {
                                row.Add(valueString);
                            }
                            else if (field is null)
                            {
                                row.Add(field);
                            }
                        }
                        if (row.Any())
                        {
                            rows.Add(row);
                        }
                    }
                } while (reader.NextResult());

            }
        }
        // CSV Writer
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\{User}\\Desktop\\sample.csv"))
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
        {
            foreach (var i in rows)
            {
                foreach (var field in i)
                {
                    csv.WriteField(field);
                }
                csv.NextRecord();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This program convert Excel (sample.xlsx) file to CSV(sample.csv) File.

Dependencies :

- ExcelDataReader.DataSet (https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader)
- CsvHelper (https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)
- System.Text.Encoding.CodePages(https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Encoding.CodePages/)

Comment: I'm having 2 problems with this code, although I think it might work. The first problem is that I have different types in my exel(string, int-s, date-time etc) and it throw an exception : `Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'`. I tried doing : `row.Add(Convert.ToString(reader.GetString(i)));` but still doesn't work. Any idea? While the second problem is that the `ResultsCount = 4 ` but I have 179rows and 19 different columns. Any idea why this happens? Maybe happens a problem while reading the exel file? Thank you :) @omansak

Comment: my bad `ResultsCount returns the number of sheets in the current workbook` . i am working on this

Comment: @Pavel ok i fixed you can use

Comment: Ok @omansak this are another few problems. First one is that the code you gave me throws an exception : ` ExcelDataReader: Index was outside the bounds of the array.` So I modified your code a little bit and I added: `for (int i = 0; i <= reader.FieldCount -1; i++)` . The xception is gone but the problem is that when I open the csv there is only one row written. Any Idea? I also removed the code you added to parse the date time, int, bool etc because I store my rows only as string so I used : `row.Add(Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(i)));` . Is this a good practice? Thank you :)

Comment: I also removed the row.Clear(). It seems to work now. I will accept your answer in 1 hour. I also edited the code to based on my request. You can take a look. Thank you. @omansak :D

Comment: yes `row.Add(Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(i)));` is nice if you need just string value

Answer (score -1):

Create a class file that would contain attributes which are same to that of your excel columns. 
Parse through your excel files and load it into the instance of your class. Write a simple program as follows

```
void Main()
{
    var records = new List<Foo>
    {
        new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "one" },
    };

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
    {
        csv.WriteRecords(records);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Where Foo is the class file. 
Hope this helps

Comment: No @sri this does not help, because every exel has different rows, so I can't write a class `Foo` . I want to read them in a dynamic way. For example every first row of exel will be the keys(or column names) and the other rows will be the values.

Comment: do you mean to say that each row will have different number of columns ?? if not you can always read the data from second row and transofrm it to an entitet

Comment: @Sri, No, IMO OP is saying that 'different files' (every excel) will have different column headers, and he wants to use the same class to read these different excel files.